# C# Insert DATE into ORACLE -- A non-numeric character Error?

Tags: c#, oracle, to-date

I am trying to insert a date from C# into an Oracle DATE field.

Here is the format that I have currently..

```
to_date('2008/06/09', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

I have verified that my date is a valid date, and that it is in the format expected.  The above throws the oracle error about a non-numeric character being found where a numeric character was expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of converting string Date to `DateTime` or `Date` in Oracle, you should convert it to `DateTime` in C# code and then pass it as parameter with your Oracle command.

Comment: I will give that a shot..  I am already converting it to a C# date time and then using the to string format to make sure it is in the same format as my to_date function is expecting.  If I understand what you are suggesting correctly, you are saying if I convert to a datetime in C# and use a paramater, I will not need to use the to_date, is tat correct?

Comment: yes that is correct.